# Completion handler in Swift requires odd underscore characters

Tags: swift, syntax, parameters, anonymous-function

I just created a method with a completion handler. I am unable to compile my application, unless I add annoying underscore characters to my method like so:

```
func searchForLocation(name: String, completion: @escaping (_ results: Array<Any>, _ error: NSError) -> ()) {  }
```

Why can I just define my method as:

```
func searchForLocation(name: String, completion: @escaping (results: Array<Any>, error: NSError) -> ()) {  }
```

This certainly makes no sense, because Apple are able to create their own completion handlers without the annoying underscore characters, for example:

```
open func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) -> URLSessionDataTask
```

Comment: Apart from the issue don't use `NSError` in Swift 4

Comment: @vadian I wanted to just use ```Error```, but in my method there is a section where I need to return my own custom error object. And unlike ```NSError```, I can't find a method that will allow me to create a ```Error``` object.

Comment: `Error` is a protocol. You can use everything which conforms to that protocol. To create custom errors please look at [Swift Language Guide: Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your function declaration as:

```
func searchForLocation(name: String, completion: @escaping (Array<Any>, NSError) -> ()) { ... }
```

This is because, you can't use `named` parameters in the closure.

Comment: Oh right I see. You can't use names in completion handlers, like you can in ```Objective-C```?

Comment: Kind of. You just can't use parameter names in the closure when you use it as a completion handler.